Maximal Element of Set {ℤ U {A}}
Lets say we have an element, denoted $A$, which is incomparable to any integers.
Then does the set $Y:=\mathbb{Z}\: \cup\: \{A\}$ have $A$ as a maximal element, since technically for any element $z \in \mathbb{Z}$, $z\not< A$ - as $A$ is not comparable with any integer?
Furthermore, is $A$ also a minimal element, since for any element $z \in \mathbb{Z}$, $z\not> A$ - again, for the same reasoning?
I was doing some set theory mental gymnastics, and needed some help with this question in my head I got stuck on. Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot!

if $A$ is not comparable to any $z\in\Bbb Z$, the statements $z\not<A$ and $z\not>A$ are not defined.

@paulina, I think this question is most likely talking about the notion of "comparability" from partial orders, in which case the statements $z \not< A$ and $z \not> A$ are defined and indeed OP's reasoning is correct (it's not totally clear though). OP, can you say a bit more about exactly what everything is here? Is $Y$ indeed intended to be a poset?

@IzaakvanDongen Thanks a lot for the clarification - Yep, I was intending Y to be a poset. In that case, would my reasoning be correct as you commented?

If $\leq$ denotes a preorder on $Y$ (not only on $\mathbb Z\subseteq Y$) and no $y\in Y$ exists with $A<y$ the $A$ is by definition a maximal element. Similar story for $A$ as minimal element.
